# Is it possible to restore data from a table in sql server 2005 to sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, restore

A client has no option but to migrate from sql server 2000 to 2008 within the next few days. Tests have shown unacceptable performance degradation in vital functionality in 2005 but not in 2008.  Good stuff however, the application uses DTS to import external market data into the database and DTS is no longer supported by 2008.

Until such time as the function can be rewritten, I'm thinking the import could be done in an instance of 2005 and the data (from one table) subsequently uploaded into 2008.

(a) is there an alternative option?
(b) if not, is there a simple way of achieving the data upload from 2005 to 2008?

Any assistance/advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding what you need to do, but one thing you can do to move a database from from 2005 to 2008 is to just back up the database on the 2005 instance to a .bak file: right-click on the database in the Object Explorer in Management Studio (or whatever it's called in your version of SQL Server!), and do Tasks -> Backup database, and save it somewhere you can see from both instances. Then go to the 2008 instance do "Tasks -> Restore database" in the 2008 instance and the restored copy of the database should just work in 2008.

I think you might have trouble going the other way though, with this method.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply: the problem is that 2005 has performance issues which do not exist in 2008, whereas 2005 has DTS and 2008 does not.  The client is considering Production running 2008 and as a DTS workaround I'm thinking the market data import could go into a 'test' 2005 instance and the data table then uploaded into the 2008 Prod DB.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. That'll teach me to read the question more carefully (!). I'm afraid I don't know anything about DTS, though.

Comment: Would it be possible to leave the market data in the 2005 instance and have some kind of view in the 2008 instance that looks across to the other instance? I've never tried anything like that...

Comment: Interesting thought...however the market data is used fairly extensively in formula calculations and I have a feeling a large chunck of code and many scripts would need rewriting.

Comment: But I mean, if you gave the view on the 2008 instance the same name as the table had originally, then maybe nothing would notice. (Although I've no idea if that's practical in this case)

Comment: The DB is accessed using ODBC and I don't recall it being possible to connect or view across multiple DBs before.  Also, there are several table joins to other data tables so not sure how easy that would be :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use an SSIS package to execute the DTS packge, and AFAIK you can execute DTS 32 bit in SQL 2008 ([MS link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440.aspx)). The other option would be to run the database in a compatibility mode which ~may~ avoid the performance issues you're seeing. All in all, you might be better off rewriting your DTS with SSIS. The concepts similar and you shouldn't have too much trouble recreating it with SSIS.

Comment: Thanks - the DTS part of the application is handled from within the application itself. I'm assuming we wouldn't be able to use SSIS to execute the DTS functionality without some kind of rewrite, hence my thoughts on a temporary stop-gap.

Comment: Given that the DTS execution lives within the application, I think you're correct that you'll need the stop gap. Granted it's not the most elegant solution, but given system constraints, I think that what you've got proposed is the best stop gap until you can upgrade to SSIS.